# JSON to XML conversion in AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, json

There are options to do it using Java and JS. And these options can be clubbed with AS3 but is there something out-of-the-box in native AS3 to do it.

Comment: I'm really curious as to what you believe XML will give you over JSON.

Comment: This is not a question of JSON vs XML. There is an application which formats URL response. It takes XML input. For XML URL responses it's fine, I need to do it for JSON responses.

Answer (score 2):

You want AS3CoreLib, found [here](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib). While it's not an 'out of box' solution, you'll notice that the library has Adobe copyright headers in the comments. It's an Adobe supported project, and it's really quite handy for a lot of things.

Answer (score 0):

Flashplayer 11 provides native JSON String parsing.
Take a look at his blogpost which explains the usage of the JSON-API:
http://blog.infrared5.com/2011/07/working-with-native-json-in-flash-player-11/